# How to say "I fell on my ass"?

Tags: phrases, english-to-japanese

Is 「お尻には落ちた」 the correct way to say "I fell on my ass"?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I fell on my ass.

「尻餅｛しりもち｝をついた」

「私、しりもちついちゃった。」

[image]

[image]

Comment: `つく` -> fell なので過去形で・・・一応・・・

Comment: Hmm, I'll never be able to eat 餅 the same way again...

Comment: Great answer, thank you.  How to say: I almost fell on my ass.

Comment: @Nutkin >I almost fell on my ass. ①（もう）すんでのところで、しりもち（を）つきそうだったよ。　②（おー危｛あぶ｝ない危｛あぶ｝ない！）しりもち（を）つくとこ（ろ）だった‌​よ。

Comment: @istrasci The expression derives from the similarity between 餅つき (consult youtube for how it's done if you like) and falling, rather than the similarity between 餅 and butts. At least so I understand. Does this perhaps make your life easier?

Comment: Well, after this picture I will never forget how to express falling on my ass in Japanese. Not sure if it helps with eating 餅 though

Comment: `尻もち(short for 尻もちつき) Pounding rice with the ass` -> 「尻もちをつく」は「尻でもちをつく」ということではなく、「尻餅とは、祝い餅のひとつ。生後1歳に満たない子供が歩くと、親を凌ぐ大物になるという言われから行われる風習行事に由来する。 **歩き出した子供に1升の米、または餅を背負わせ、後にその餅をお尻に投げつけ** (←わざと倒して) 子供の成長を祝う。投げつけられた餅が尻餅である。・・・『尻餅を突く』と言う言葉はこの餅から来ている」([Wiki尻餅](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B0%BB%E9%A4%85)) あるいは「子供の初めての誕生日を祝ってつく餅。初めての誕生日より前に立って歩いた子供は早く家を出て行くといって、**この餅を背負わせてわざと倒したり**する。」([デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/112626/meaning/m0u/)) 辺りからきていると思うのですが。

Comment: @Chocolate > 尻餅とは、祝い餅のひとつ。生後1歳に満たない子供が歩くと、親を‌​凌ぐ大物になるという言われから行われる風‌​習行事に由来。これは正解くさいです。私もいろいろ調べて回答をしておりますが、風習説の方が好きです。漢字も「搗く」が正しいとの説にも辿り着いておりますが、風習説なら尻餅を「突く」が納得です。ぜひ新Answerにあげてください。応援します。

Comment: @Chocolate 私自身は今の回答を考える前は、尻餅（落語）（wiki）にあるぺったんぺったんの擬音語の世界かなっと思っておりました。また、私の回答にあるお尻と杵（きね）の置き換えでなく、お餅とお尻がぷっくらして似ているためのつながりかなっと思っておりました。但し、これでは、falling （ころぶ）こととつながらないので何故かなとの疑問もあり、お尻と杵の置き換え説に至ったわけです。

Comment: @Yosh: No, because my brain already made the association between 餅 and butts, regardless of the correctness of it.  (>_<)